# C# Using Variable To Switch Between Two Lists

Tags: list, c3.js

This may be a silly question, but here is my scenario: I have two lists, one containing hockey player objects and another containing baseball player objects.

```
public static List<BaseballPlayer> Baseball List = new List<BaseballPlayer>();
public static List<HockeyPlayer> Hockey List = new List<HockeyPlayer>();
```

I have one screen that draws more details on a player object if a button is pushed (the below is an example of hundreds of lines drawn):

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(x, y, 130, 32),Lists.BaseballPlayer[i].accessPlayerName);
```

However, is there a way to dynamically control which list name is used. So something like:

```
string one;
```

And then have the draw call do something like this:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(x, y, 130, 32),Lists.one[i].accessPlayerName);
```

Where string one can be defined as either "BaseballPlayers" or "HockeyPlayers".

I don't want to have to duplicate two screens, one showing the BaseballPlayer list and one showing the HockeyPlayer list. If there were a way to dynamically insert the list name, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a simple if inline can be enough.

Suppose you use a boolean to determine which list use:

```
bool useHockey = true; //control this variable anyway you like, a property, a function, anything you want
```

Then you can do:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(x, y, 130, 32), (useHockey ? Lists.Hockey : Lists.Baseball)[i].accessPlayerName);
```

Comment: This is very close to the solution I need. Unfortunately, the bool only activates the one list, not the other. For example, selecting useHockey to true successfully activates the hockey list, but setting it to false also selects the hockey list. Could be I'm missing something here though?

Comment: If it's true it will use the Hockey list, if it's false it will use the Baseball list... an inline if can be resumed like: *if(useHockey == true)Lists.Hockey; else Lists.Baseball;*

Comment: Something's wrong on my end then. I see the bool switching appropriately between true and false, but the display always acts as if it is true. Tested this with both Debug and printed text showing the bool state. Very strange.

Comment: Got it working! I had an issue with the bool. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The ideal case would be using inheritance. Since both `HockeyPlayer` and `BaseballPlayer` are `Player`'s with some common properties, it would be better to create a base class and put common properties there.

After that the printing function would be much easier:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BaseballPlayer : Player
{
    //Properties specific to baseball player
}

public class HockeyPlayer : Player
{
    //Properties specific to hockey player
}

public void PrintPlayers(List<Player> playerList)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.Count; i++)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(x, y, 130, 32),playerList[i].Name);
    }
}

PrintPlayer(Lists.BaseballPlayers);
PrintPlayer(Lists.HockeyPlayers);
```

Comment: Yeah, I have definitely done that. It's just I put the Hockey and Baseball objects in different storage lists. But I want to use the same draw screen for either list, with the list name being the variable selected on input.

Comment: They do not have to be in the same list. `PrintPlayer(Lists.BaseballPlayers);` and `PrintPlayer(Lists.HockeyPlayers);` already covers the case they are in separate lists.